# good practice to import asterisk for package/lib?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I've seen somewhere in github people import `*`, I have no clue why he did so, for instance:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export const doSomething = () => {
  return React.useMemo(() => {
    return {
      something: window.location.href
    };
  }, []);
};
```

He did the same for other packages. Why don't we do

`import { useMemo } from 'react'` ?

Comment: What i've seen as the most common is import React from 'react'; and then just use React.useMemo()

Answer (score 0):

Both of the suggestions for using `*` or explicit imports are possible and will work as expected.
The asterix will import all components, hooks, and more artifacts that are located under the "react" library, so when using

```
import * from "react";
```

you'll have the freedom to use any type of hook or Component without an explicit import.

The best practice though is to import only modules that are relevant to your application or components

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
```

This approach will make sure you don't import unused components that will be heavy on your bundle size for production and will be flagged as dead code.

Comment: then the answer should be the second one, only import the method that you only need. I don't see * is good practice, no?

Comment: Yes, using explicit imports is preferred over using `*`

Comment: then what's the `*` for and when is it right to use it since it's 'bad'?

Comment: Using `*` will just impact your application bundle, some devs don't mind the bundle size or the dead code so they will use it anyway.
If you are using heavily all types of "react" imports, instead of import them manually one by one you can simply use the asterix to import it all at once. I personally don't use asterix very often, but I would consider using it when I need to build something quickly as a POC or a code snippet but not something that is intended to go to production.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to expand my answer I will say: You have two options

1. `import React, { useMemo } from 'react';`

Benefits? You are just importing the things you need, also, your code will be a little bit shorter compared to the second option since you can use useMemo(); directly

Also this is the way reactjs.org presents their examples https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html which is a big -GOOD PRACTICE- signal

2. `import React from 'react';`

it's seem similar to the first option but you are using React directly.
how to access `useMemo()`? `React.useMemo()`. So yes, you guessed, it's a little bit longer sintax that the first option, but i do not think this is a problem.

Also this is the way https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/ material ui presents their examples. It's also a nice way to do it (and the one I use)

Comment: I'm asking why you shouldn't be doing only import stuff that you need?

Comment: Basically, shorter import sentence and short call for all the items e.g useMemo()

Comment: then what's the * for and when is it right to use it since it's 'bad'?